# Design of Experiment vs Sensitivity Analysis

Tags: statistics

What is the difference between the Design of Experiments (DOE) and sensitivity analysis? By reading the explanation of both the analyses it seems they are the same thing.

Comment: Does anybody have any idea about how they are different?

Comment: Really would be grateful if someone can help me understand this please

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see it, Design of experiments require some sort of info on the sensitivity in order to give an answer.
By this I mean that in order to optimally select/design an input to an experiment, we need an estimate on how the output reacts to input (and how uncertainty is propagated), i.e. some sensitivity analysis.
Alternatively, if no such info is available, methods of randomization or spreading the experiments out can be said to be "experiment design".

I would however not say that sensitivity analysis is a subdicipline of DoE, since it is a broad subject.
DoE can be done hueristically from knowledge on sensitivities, but also analytically, using optimization techniques and info on your system that goes far deeper than what is "needed" for analyzing sensitivities.

As you indicate, they are connected, though with different objectives. Experiment design is about trying to make good information with little effort, sensitivity analysis seems to rather analyze your responses and/or explain interactions (and interactions is a also sub-part of DOE).